# XAML DataTrigger exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, datatrigger

I'm dynamically adding columns to a datatable / datagrid (DataGridTemplateColumn) at runtime, then showing the cell data (file paths) as buttons with a DataTemplate. Since many of the cells won't have file paths... I'm trying to make those cells empty by using a DataTrigger, but I'm getting the error:

> 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.Template' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '35' and line position '14'.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2Copy">
        <Button Name="fileButton" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value ="noLINK">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Images\PDFicon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here's where it's called & error highlighted:

```
private void masterSetDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "FileName")
        e.Column.Header = "File Name";

    else
    {
        string origHeader = e.Column.Header.ToString();

        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn    //Error highlighting starts here
        {
            Header = origHeader,
            CellTemplate = (DataTemplate) Resources["DataTemplate2Copy"]
        };                              //Error highlighting ends here
        e.Column = templateColumn;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the inner exception? Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to say for sure what's going wrong, but it sure looks like you've got a problem retrieving the template or assigning it. Please improve your question.

Comment: You are missing the `Binding` in your `Datatrigger`